# Operaciones con columnas de DataFrames

Tags: pandas, python-3.7

Dispongo del siguiente DataFrame

```
d = {'Ticker': ["Total_Pond", "Total_Pond", "Total_Pond", "ValorRelativo", "Avantage","Acatis" ],
        'Tipo_Inv': ["FI", "FI", "FI", "FI","FI", "FI"], 'Fact_Pond': [2.313857e+06, 1.342821e+06,3.486820e+06,2.788324e+06, 4.929096e+06, 2.663564e+06],
        'Total_Pond': [-53196.922835, -37853.091155, -114935.107120, -26013.111409,374923.428199, -235590.992103 ]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

Intento calcular el interés medio ponderado  de cada valor, para lo cual pivoto la tabla y añado la columna ***df_Imp_valor***  con el resultado de la división  **["Total_Pond"]**   entre **df ["Fact_Pond"]**

```
# Interes medio ponderado de cada valor
df_Imp_valor = pd.pivot_table(df,index=["Ticker"],values=['Fact_Pond', 'Total_Pond' ],aggfunc=np.sum)
df_Imp_valor["Int_Med_Pond_Val"] = df ["Total_Pond"]/  df ["Fact_Pond"]
df_Imp_valor[:3]
```

El resultado no es correcto, ya que añade NaN al valor de dicha columna.

```
          Fact_Pond     Total_Pond     Int_Med_Pond_Val
Ticker          
Acatis    2663564.0     -235590.992103    NaN
Avantage    4929096.0   374923.428199      NaN
Total_Pond  7143498.0   -205985.121110     NaN
```

Compruebo de otra manera, que el resultado de la división es un número

```
a = df ["Total_Pond"]
b = df ["Fact_Pond"] 
a/b

0   -0.022991
1   -0.028189
2   -0.032963
3   -0.009329
4    0.076063
5   -0.088450
dtype: float64
```

Seguramente estoy obcecado. ¿cuál es el error que cometo?. 
Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entiendo que la división quieres hacerla sobre el resultado de pivotar, y no sobre las columnas de la tabla original.

El problema es que aquí:

```
df_Imp_valor["Int_Med_Pond_Val"] = df ["Total_Pond"]/  df ["Fact_Pond"]
```

divides columnas del dataframe original `df` *pero asignas el resultado* al dataframe resultado de pivotar, que tiene otros índices. Ya que los índices no coinciden, en el resultado de la división no hay filas correspondientes a los nombres de los ticker, y por eso lo rellena con `NaN`.

Haciendolo así:

```
df_Imp_valor = pd.pivot_table(df,index=["Ticker"],values=['Fact_Pond', 'Total_Pond' ],aggfunc=np.sum)
df_Imp_valor["Int_Med_Pond_Val"] = df_Imp_valor["Total_Pond"]/  df_Imp_valor["Fact_Pond"]
df_Imp_valor
```

El resultado ya sale correcto:

```
              Fact_Pond     Total_Pond  Int_Med_Pond_Val
Ticker                                                   
Acatis         2663564.0 -235590.992103         -0.088450
Avantage       4929096.0  374923.428199          0.076063
Total_Pond     7143498.0 -205985.121110         -0.028835
ValorRelativo  2788324.0  -26013.111409         -0.009329
```

Comment: Efectivamente, ese era mi problema. df_Imp_valor es otro dataframe y, por lo tanto, las operaciones deben hacerse utilizando sus columnas. Muchas gracias